# Cannot get a proper file output in C on Debian

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to Debian and C. Tried to write a program which reads test.txt file and produces temp.txt file, which is then being renamed to test.txt. However, every time I run the program, I get unreadable output. Also, the program doesn't read the file from the working directory, so I had to use the full path instead. I there a way to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define FILENAME "/home/deusi/Programming/Personal/C/toUpperCase/test.txt"
#define TEMPFILE "/home/deusi/Programming/Personal/C/toUpperCase/temp.txt"

int main() {

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    FILE *temp = NULL;
    char ch;
    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        perror("File DNE");
        return -1;
    }

    temp = fopen(TEMPFILE, "w");

    if(!temp) {
        return -1;
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF)) {

        if(islower(ch)) {
            ch = ch-32;
        }
        fputc(ch,temp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(temp);

    rename(TEMPFILE, FILENAME);
    remove(TEMPFILE);

    if(!fp) {
        return -1;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No matter what I put in the test file, I get an output of the type

Comment: You've closed fp but then at the end you try reading from it - that isn't going to work... Also how can you delete TEMPFILE if you just renamed it?

Comment: It's that time of the year again. `fgetc` returns `int`, not `char`. There is a reason for that.  There is about a zillion questions about it here on SO. That's in addition to all other problems mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors, but one that messes up your output is here:

```
while((ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF)) {
```

Here you are assigning to `ch` the value of `fgetc(fp) != EOF`. It should be;

```
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
```